# check if a $var is an int or an array

Tags: php, arrays

In a constructor of a object, I would like to be able to pass an int variable (representing a id to then fetch to database) or an array (when i already fetched to database)

I tried something like this:

```
__construct($var){
     if(isset($var['id'])){ /*tried also if($var['id']) != '')*/
        $this->id = $var['id'];
     }else{
        $this->id = $var;
      }
}
```

The thing is that by passing a int value parameter as $var, it will enter to the first case on the if.

So how can i propper check that $var is an (asociative) array ?

Comment: [`is_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `is_int ($var)` to check if it is an int and `is_array ($var)` if it is an array

Answer (score 1):

You can use php `is_array()` and `is_int()` function

```
if(is_array($var)){
        $this->id = $var['id'];
     }else{
        $this->id = $var;
      }
```

or

```
if(is_int($var)){
           $this->id = $var;
         }elseif(is_array($var)){           
           $this->id = $var['id'];
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two different ways to check:
[`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php), which will return a string with the type

```
$type = gettype($var);
switch($type) {
    case 'array':
        // ....
        break;
    case 'integer':
        // ...
        break;
    // ....
}
```

and also

[`is_int()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php), respectively [`is_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), which, somehow not surprisingly, return `boolean` value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (is_array($var)) ...
```